# Can I apply alter the labels of all x variables without changing them individually?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a geom_col() with a lot of x variables, each labeled something like ABC, DEF, etc... Is there a function that will allow me to alter the existing labels all at once so that they become ABC∆, DEF∆, etc?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data. While the general answer to your question is probably "yes" it lacks the necessary details and clarity to give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a labelling function to the `labels` argument of `scale_x_discrete`. This takes the default label and does whatever you like to it. Here we can use a tidyverse-style lambda function to `paste` the symbol Δ to the end of each label

```r
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "KLM"),
                 y = c(3, 5, 7, 4))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = ~ paste0(.x, "\u0394"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>